# Fetch data from MySQL when selecting different option from dropdown menu

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dropdown user list (which is generated by database info) and I'm looking for a way to load some extra information from the database every time I choose a different user from the dropdown menu. (without reloading the page)

```
<select class="form-control" id="Users" name="Users">
      <option value="0" selected> - </option>
<?php
$query=$MMM->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_status = 1 ORDER BY user_id ASC");
while ($data = $MMM->fetch($query)) {
?>
      <option value="<?php echo $data['user_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $data['user_name']; ?> </option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

And here is the table I'm trying to "reload" every time I chose a different user from the dropdown menu

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xs">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th class="text-center">Username</th>
              <th class="text-center">Name</th>
              <th class="text-center">Email</th>
              <th class="text-center">City</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          User Info will go here
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible to do achieve this with PHP?

Comment: You're looking for AJAX.

Comment: I am looking for something similar, where we select the first dropdown list and the remaining things will change according this selection. My understanding it is only possible using JQuery script. I keep you informed :-).

Comment: I found this one [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803193/how-to-create-3-depended-dropdown-list-using-php-ajax-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803193/how-to-create-3-depended-dropdown-list-using-php-ajax-jquery) and I believe will sort your issue.